# Show that a Linear Transformation exists

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear transformation ***$T: {\rm I\!R^{3}->\rm I\!R^{2}}$***
$T(1, 0, 3) = (1,1)$
$T(-2, 0, 6) = (2, 1)$

Now I want to show that a linear transformation exists with these properties.
I thought that If I showed that$(1, 0, 3)$ & $(-2, 0, 6)$ are linearly independent then
they would span ${\rm I\!R^{3}}$, thus also ${\rm I\!R^{2}}$ 
but that doesn't seem right since I only have
Two vectors in ${\rm I\!R^{3}}$.

Would I have to add another vector or am I going about this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$T = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\d & e &f\end{bmatrix}. \tag 1$$
You need to determine $T$ such that 
$$T \begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 \\0 & 0 \\3 & 6\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}. \tag 2$$
Use $(1)$ and $(2)$ to determine $T$. You will see that there are infinite many $T$s that satisfy the given conditions. One such $T$ is given below.
$$T =\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1/3 \\1/4 & 0 & 1/4 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Just out of curiosity how did you find such a T?

Comment: I've mentioned the procedure in the answer. You plug in the value $T$ given in $(1)$ in $(2)$ to determine $a$, $b$, etc. You will need to solve a system of linear equations to determine them.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $T(0,1,0)=(0,0)$. Then $T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\left(\frac{1}{3}x_3,\frac{1}{4}x_1+\frac{1}{4}x_3\right)$, $T(1,0,3)=(1,1)$, $T(-2,0,6)=(2,1)$.

$(1,0,3), (-2,0,6)$ can't span $\mathbf{R}^3$ because $\dim\mathrm{span}\left\{(1,0,3), (-2,0,6)\right\}=2\neq 3 = \dim \mathbf{R}^3$

Comment: so it can't be a linear transform?

Comment: @Aldrec I just showed it is. I chose vector $(0,1,0)$, $(0,1,0),(1,0,3),(-2,0,6)$ form a basis of $\mathbf{R}^3$ and sent it to arbitrary vector, here $(0,0)$. It follows from the fact that linear transformation is uniquely determined by it's values on basis vecors.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is an infinite number of such linear transformations. Since $(1,0,3)$ and $(-2,0,6)$ are linearly independent, their images under $T$ can be anything without violating linearity. Choose any vector that’s not in their span so that you have a basis for $\mathbb R^3$. You may then choose anything in $\mathbb R^2$ to be this vector’s image.